# Test for CreateSQLQuery

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sqlite, nunit

I use `NHibernate CreateSQLQuery` method to get DTO objects of my departments.

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM Departments";
IList<Object[]> resultList = Session.CreateSQLQuery(query)...
```

and it works well. But also I want to write a test and it fails when I write:

```
 [Test]
 public void CanGetTreeDto()
  {

            IList<DepartmentDto> resultList =  _departmentRepository.GetTreeListDto(idContract);
...
        }
```

It throws `SQLiteException` and writes "could not execute query". Could anybody help?

Comment: please post the full exception stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You need [ad-hoc mapping](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/06/30/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%253A%20LosTechies%20%2528LosTechies%2529):

```
IList<DepartmentDto> result = Session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
                                     .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(DepartmentDto)))
                                     .List<DepartmentDto>();
```

Also, you **might** need to be explicit about the columns as well as its names.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved my problem. In 'query = @"SELECT * FROM Departments";' I used CTE wich doesn't support by SQLite. Thanks for answer